# Conditionally instantiate member variable on presence of constexpr definition

Tags: c++, constexpr, sfinae

I have a class Foo in a namespace that I would like to have a member variable conditionally defined based on a condition. In C, I would have expressed this using an `ifdef`, but defines suffer from not being namespace-able. Is there a way to achieve the same effect using constexpr?

The closest I've gotten to is the below, but I'd like to have it such that not having `is_field_a_present` defined results in `Bar::a` not being instantiated.

In Foo.h:

```
#include <config.h>

namespace Foo {
struct Bar {
    struct empty {};
    [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional<is_field_a_present, int32_t, empty>::type a;
};
}
```

In config.h:

```
namespace Foo {
    constexpr bool is_field_a_present = false;
}
```

Comment: You could inherite from one of two structs one having the member the other not? (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6219ba7fd608ce14)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect whether a namespace scope variable was declared or not in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: I did such a thing once ,it quickly turned out to be a bad decision. I wish you well.

Comment: “Instantiate”?  There are no templates here, so what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `std::conditional` in inheritance:

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace detail
    {
        struct empty {};
        struct with_a {int32_t a;}
    }
    
    struct Bar : std::conditional<is_field_a_present, detail::with_a, detail::empty>::type
    {
    };

}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6219ba7fd608ce14)

Note: if you do it for several fields, you should probably use different `empty` classes (you might "tag" them) to really allow EBO (if your class have several (non tagged) `empty`, they should have distinct addresses, so use extra byte).

Comment: Is there a way to achieve it such that it by default assumes detail::empty if is_field_a_present is not defined?

Comment: @cradical: To use a name, it should exist, or be template-dependent. You have no template here to make it template dependent, so name should exist.